# "Recommend Deletion" not shown on "all actions" tab

Tags: bug, review-queues, activity-tab

When looking at [my "all actions" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619912/programfox?tab=activity&sort=all), I noticed that I didn't see any "Recommend Deletion" actions of the Low Quality Posts queue, even while I did some of these reviews today. And the reason cannot be that all of the "Recommend Deletion"ed posts are already deleted, because some of them are not.

Screenshot of the "all actions" tab:

[image: All Actions tab]

And a screenshot of my Low Quality Posts review history:

[image: Low Quality Posts history]

Is it by design that "Recommend Deletion" reviews are hidden, or is this a bug?