# Does the SO profile show all review actions?

Tags: discussion, support

Yesterday I was notified by another user that an autogenerated Low Quality Post review comment was incorrect. I agree, but don't recall reviewing said item (I generally skip MATLAB questions as I don't have any experience with it). So I went to check the [reviews I'd done](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp?tab=activity&sort=reviews) in my Profile, only to find said question isn't listed there at all.

I then went and reviewed 5 LQPs today (just before posting this question), and after checking my reviews in my Profile again, only the first item I reviewed is listed.

Is this correct/intended behaviour, and if so, why? Or am I just Doing It Wrong?

*edit*: I did review that answer incorrectly and have since deleted the autogen'd comment. Hence I've also removed the comment link from this question because, well, it no longer works.

Comment: The full list will be available to you at: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?userId=70345&skipped=true

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Another question though, why are the 2 lists different?

Comment: @IanKemp Probably the reviews in your profile don't include those you "skipped" because skipping means you took no real action.

Comment: @DavidPostill Nope, I didn't skip any of the 5 items I reviewed this morning, but only 1 still appears on my profile.

Comment: @IanKemp Strange ;)

Comment: Probably because the review tab in your profile is public and links to  deleted posts shouldn't be accessible from there. I'm not sure if this applies to your case.

Comment: Related: [“Recommend Deletion” not shown on “all actions” tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291446/recommend-deletion-not-shown-on-all-actions-tab)

Comment: I suspect, your action history doesn't show the questions which are already invisible for you. And, if the posts are already deleted, then you can't see them, except some rare circumstances (you still can see your own posts, but you can't get reviews about them, so they won't go into your review history. Or, you can see the posts you've reviewed in your own review history, even if they were deleted, but only their state at the time of the review. This exception probably doesn't happen for your activity history.)