# Show all review actions, including suggested deletions even when review banned

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues

This is related to a previous [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308018/does-the-so-profile-show-all-review-actions) about what is and isn't shown on the review tab of your profile.

#### Background:

I reviewed something in the Low Quality Posts that a moderator disagreed with and was hit with a review ban. It was not an audit that I failed. When I go to review, I am presented with an warning message that links to the single review that I was banned for and tells me to come back in a few days after reviewing it.

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: [link to review]
>
> Come back in 5 days to continue reviewing.

I've reviewed that one, but now I want to see all of my recent reviews to see if I should be adjusting how I review. Unfortunately, my profile only shows things that I've selected "Looks OK" to. The review queue itself tells me to come back in a few days without the option to look at previous reviews.

I can access these previous reviews *if* I know the full path to the review queue history and manipulate the URL to get there (shown in the comments on the linked question).

#### Request

I'd like to be able to access my previous reviews, either in my profile or in the associated review queues, at any point in time. I'd like to be able to do this without URL manipulation to get to the queue history.

The message encourages me to look at the single review that I did incorrectly. I would like to see my previous history so that I can compare that failure to other recent reviews I've done.

Comment: No http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews for you?

Comment: What the heck with all those "looks ok"? BTW, /review is accessible to anyone, even anonymous users.

Comment: It shows 7 "Looks OK" reviews from today. I did 30 Low Quality reviews total. I'm asking that the other 23 the ones that I didn't think look OK be shown as well.

Comment: At the risk of sounding rude, @Braiam, did you read what I wrote? `/review` is not accessible to review banned. I get a message telling me which review I did poorly on and told to come back. That's it. I can't see any of the queues. I can't access any history without URL manipulations. Without the exact URL to the queue history, I can only see the "Looks OK" reviews in my profile. I can't see the ones that I wanted to delete.

Comment: Well, I told you that "/review is accessible to anyone, **even anonymous users.**", so why not trying that instead?

Comment: The only thing wrong I'm seeing here is that none of your non-"Looks Ok" reviews are shown, which is a bug... not a FR.

Comment: This is a feature request to either attach those to a user's profile or to make the queue histories accessible to all (even the review banned). I don't know if the current implementation is by design or not. As such, I decided to go with "feature request" to change the current behavior instead of "bug" to say that it's currently wrong.

Comment: The issue with going the anonymous user route is that if the post has been deleted, it's not accessible to such a user (lack of rep), even though I'd be able to see if I had the URL (as a 10K+ user). All I'd see is the results of the review, but not the post itself.

Comment: @Andy userscript time? A userscript could hold you in some kind of hybrid logged in / logged out state and combine data from both views. It won't be easy to write, I guess, but it should be doable.

Comment: Regarding reviews not shown in your profile: [“Recommend Deletion” not shown on “all actions” tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291446/recommend-deletion-not-shown-on-all-actions-tab)

Comment: Now that you have a ♦, do you have any more sway with the powers that be to implement this? I was doing some research before asking my own question (my motivation being that I wanted to see the 'correct' total number of reviews in my [reviews tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews), but it looks like your question covered it already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are now links to your review history for each queue available to you on the /review page while you are review suspended, and you should be able to load these pages without issue. You will be able to access this easily through the notice in the topbar reviews dropdown. Read about our [new improved experience for users with review suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/51) for more info.

---

> review suspended,
> now you’ll find your history.
> load, learn, up your game!