# User profile - see total reviews count

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Since I got past the 3k limit, I can now see and contribute to all types of reviews.

I like it. And it gives me a nice feeling to be able to help out with this type of activity (yes, occasionally i mess up a review or two, but it's not the point *here*).

I was wondering if the total number of reviews can be listed in the `IMPACT` panel.

I'm not asking this for badge tracking purposes (found some posts related to this), but a "grand total" of reviews. Something like "post edits" or "helpful flags". It doesn't even need to be a hyperlink. Just a text.

I, for one, would like to see that info.
There's no place I can get my hands on that number (except summing up the numbers for each review type).
In my oppinion, it's a pretty important metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of reviews performed is already in your profile, under "all actions" in the Activity tab.

Yours is https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181435/alex-tartan?tab=activity&sort=reviews.

Comment: gotta admit, that was the last place I thought of looking. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure all reviews appear here, and the numbers don't add up. I've done over 3.7k reviews in just the LQP queue (and about 4k in others when combined), but on my profile it says 3.5k total reviews.

Comment: Hmm, you're right @TZHX, I'm about 9k down. Glancing through, I can't see anything on deleted posts in there/

Comment: [“Recommend Deletion” not shown on “all actions” tab"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291446/recommend-deletion-not-shown-on-all-actions-tab)