# If a flag is disputed, can we display how other reviewers flagged?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, flags, disputed-flags

Having recently gained the reputation to access the review queues (yay!) I've had a few disputed flags.

Currently, it shows a message like this:

[image: disputed flag description]

I think it would be quite helpful to see how other reviewers categorised the question so that reviewers can learn from disputed flags (I don't think it is currently possible to see how others flagged?).

For example:

1. Alice flags a question as off-topic.
2. Bob flags the question as a duplicate. Oh noes! The flag is disputed.
3. Alice sees that the question was disputed because it was marked as a possible duplicate.
4. Alice looks at the question again, realises that the duplicate flag was a better fit, and makes a mental note to look more carefully for duplicates next time. (Perhaps there would even be an option for Alice to take back her flag.)

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22239307)?

Comment: Aaaaaa yes exactly like that. Never noticed that before, sorry for the basic question, and thanks for helping!

Comment: Having that link in the Flags view would definitely be a nice touch.

Comment: Just wanted to drop a note thanking you for a good feature-request. No complaining about the present state, just a desire to see the experience improved. The bonus hand-drawn circle and Alice-and-Bob story put icing on the cake. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, thank you for doing your part and reviewing! It's users like you who curate the content on Stack Overflow, keeping it as invaluable a resource for programmers as it is!

Secondly, I see that [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi) has given you the answer to your initial question in [the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380354/if-a-flag-is-disputed-can-we-display-how-other-reviewers-flagged#comment671351_380354):

> Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22239307)?

You can go back to your history for, say the First Posts review queue by going to the [history link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history) on the review page:

[image: history]

then you can find the specific review corresponding to the disputed flag.

You can also see your reviews by going to Activity\All Actions\reviews on your profile page (for you it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7470360/a-jar-of-clay?tab=activity&sort=reviews)), but once you get more reputation and access to more review queues, you'll find that [not review queue actions appear there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291446/1364007).

---

I know you've tagged this as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), but until the feature gets added I'lll show you another way to find out information about your flags. This will work even on posts that you **didn't** flag from review.

I'll work through an example for a disputed off-topic flag of my own (it's from 2015 because once I got 3k reputation I lost the ability to flag posts for closure and instead was able to [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30528912/1364007):

> [image: disputed off-topic flag]

If I hover over the "disputed" then I can see exactly when the flag became disputed:

> [image: disputed flag with tooltip]

It's possible to see the timeline (an [experimental feature of the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262678/1364007)) of any post by right-clicking on the "edit" link at the bottom, copying the URL to the clipboard, and changing the `/edit` to `/timeline`.

> [image: edit link]

In this case I'm changing

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30528912/edit

to

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30528912/timeline

The second link then shows the timeline for that post:

> [image: timeline for post]

The question was posted at `May 29 '15 at 11:51` and immediately entered triage. The result of [the triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8249033) was:

> [image: triage result]

Nobody agreed with me, so my off-topic flag was disputed when the review was completed at 12:15.